# Rules Conditions to check changed Developer app field

Tags: rules

I want to create a rule that takes an action whenever the overallStatus field of a Developer App is changed. But how do I do this since I think I cant use app-unchanged to compare the before and after state of the field?

Does anyone know how to do this?

This is an export of my current rule so far:

```
{ "rules_update_api_key_after_approval" : {
    "LABEL" : "Update API Key after Approval",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_http_client", "devconnect_developer_apps" ],
    "ON" : { "devconnect_developer_app_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_is_of_type" : { "entity" : [ "app" ], "type" : "developer_app" } },
      { "AND" : [
          { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "app" ], "field" : "field_status" } }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "request_url" : {
          "USING" : {
            "url" : "My Company URL",
            "method" : "GET",
            "data" : "cred_status=[app:credentialStatus]\r\noverall_status=[app:overallStatus]\r\nstatus=[app:status]"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "http_response" : { "http_response" : "HTTP data" } }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note: Wwhen I access it from data comparison the field exists in app:overallStatus but when I use entity has field and choose app on the data selector, on the field selection it only shows taxonomy_forums, comment_body, body, etc and no overallStatus field. And it is Drupal 7.6.

Comment: What is a developer app? Did you attempt to write your own rules condition / action in code?

Comment: it is an entity when I used Drupal portal together with Apigee

Comment: Maybe add a condition based on the time since the last update and don't continue..? Sort of like a flood protection.

Answer (score 1):

Piece of cake:

- add a Rules Condition like "Entity has field" (for your `overallStatus` field), which will make that field available for testing in subsequent Rules Conditions and/or Rules Actions.
- add a Rules Condition (*after* the previous one, important!) to verify if the `unchanged` value of your `overallStatus` field is yes or no equal to the value of your `overallStatus` field (which is the value that would be saved).

PS: I'm assuming your question is about D7.

Comment: the thing is when I access it from data comparison the field exists in app:overallStatus but when I use entity has field and choose app on the data selector, on the field selection it only shows taxonomy_forums, comment_body, body, etc and no overallStatus field.
I'm very sorry if my questions is not good since I'm very new to using both Drupal and Apigee. And yes it is Drupal 7.6

Comment: @TaufiqAbdullahSalim please extend (edit) your question to also include an export (created using the rules UI) of the rule you already have so far (even if the rule doesn't work yet). That'll provide way more details about what exactly you're trying to do. BTW, I "think" I know what your remaining issue might be (but I don't want to guess, which is why I wonder about your current rule). Please drop me an extra comment after you updated your question.

Comment: I have updated my question with the export of my current rule